# I have a situation with compiler. When i run the code to strip a string of special characters it runs in one compiler but doesn't in another?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here is the code that produces the error in g++ 4.6.3

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); i++)
 {
  a.erase (remove(a.begin(), a.end(), chars[i]), a.end());
 }
```

The error i get is

```
error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'
```

The code runs perfectly well in code blocks 12.11.

Comment: Try to `#include <algorithm>` and specify `std::remove`, there may be conflicts of function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
#include <algorithm>
```

And use `std::remove` instead of `remove`.

Otherwise it tries to use the `remove` function which is useful to remove files and it accepts `const char*` as parameter.